# Laptop CPU power limit throttling is constantly on for no reason

Tags: laptop, cpu, throttling, cpu-throttling

I have a laptop (HP OMEN 15, Intel i7-7700HQ + NVIDIA 1050Ti, Windows 10 1809) which I run some heavy computational jobs from time to time. Everything had been working fine for months until yesterday, I found my laptop running slower and the fan noise is quieter than it usually is. The task managers shows that my CPU frequency is locked to 2.8 GHz max, but previously with 100% utilization it usually went to 3.4 GHz.

I installed Intel XTU and it shows that the CPU power limit throttling is on, even when CPU is idle and temperature is below 50 degree Celsius. The throttling is on immediately after I boot the computer. Below is what I have checked and tried so far but nothing works:

1. Disable power throttling in Group Policy.
2. Switch to high-performance power plan (maximum processor state 100%, max TDP level 45W).
3. Uninstall Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Manager/Processor Participant from device manager.
4. Increase the Turbo Boost Power Max from 45W to 65W in Intel XTU.
5. Uninstall windows update May 3, 2019—KB4495667 (OS Build 17763.475). This is the only software I have installed recently before the problem shows up.
6. So far I cannot find any CPU throttling related settings in the BIOS.

Why is the CPU get power throttled even when idle? How can I get rid of this power throttling?

Comment: Have you verified all fans are operational?